# How to read google calendar events of user after getting access token?

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I want to get google calendar events of my users in django and I wrote the following code. This code works and saves access token of user but I don't know what I should to do to get google calendar events of user after it.
I had some problem before this and asked it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608421/how-to-get-google-calendar-events-of-users-of-my-website-by-python) and tried to solve it and now I am here.
can some one help me?

in url:

```
url(r'^new_event/$', views.new_event, name="new_event"),
url(r'^oauth2_callback', OAuth2CallBack.as_view(), name='oauth2_callback'),
url(r'^access_to_google_calendar$', views.access_to_google_calendar, 
                         name="access_to_google_calendar"),
```

in view:

```
def access_to_google_calendar(request):
    # Following line is for getting google calendar events of user to show him
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(settings.CLIENT_ID_CALENDAR, 
                             settings.CLIENT_SECRET_CALENDAR,
                             scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                               redirect_uri=settings.REDIRECT_URI_CALENDAR)
    generated_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(generated_url)



class OAuth2CallBack(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        code = request.GET.get('code', False)
        if not code:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error, no access key received from Google or User declined permission!'})

        flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(settings.CLIENT_ID_CALENDAR, settings.CLIENT_SECRET_CALENDAR,
                                   scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                                   redirect_uri=settings.REDIRECT_URI_CALENDAR)
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)

        credentials_js = json.loads(credentials.to_json())
        access_token = credentials_js['access_token']
        # Store the access token in case we need it again!
        username = request.user.username
        with open('token.csv', 'w') as file:
            fieldnames = ['user', 'token']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerow({'user': username, 'token': access_token})

        request.session['access_token'] = access_token
        return redirect('new_event')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed('Only GET requests!')



def new_event(request):
        # Here how to get google event of user?????
```

Comment: Where can i contact you?

Answer (score 1):

I finally find out how to create service to get google calendar event **just having access token**:

At first you should get token that is saved before(from csv file or data base or... that here is saved in csv file)

```
token = get_from_any_where_you_saved_it_before
```

and then: (first line is important in this case)

```
credentials = client.AccessTokenCredentials(token, 'USER_AGENT')
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
google_calendar_events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
google_calendar_events = google_calendar_events.get('items', [])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Documentation for Google calendar there is sample code for most of the methods.   [events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

```
page_token = None
while True:
  events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token).execute()
  for event in events['items']:
    print event['summary']
  page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I create "service" in  "new_event" def and is this "page_token" that token I get and save in "OAuth2CallBack" class?

Comment: Have you tried checking this?  https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

Comment: Yes, and I had a problem with it. I said it in another question that just some one comment for it. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608421/how-to-get-google-calendar-events-of-users-of-my-website-by-python)

Comment: I finally found the solution and added it.